# Exporting selected rows in a custom format in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am writing a Shiny application that allows the user to input a CSV file and convert it to a specific XML specifications (OPML, the standard for RSS feeds).

My current issue is uniting the ability to select specific rows **and** export in the custom format. I can export everything together with the standard `downloadButton()` with a custom function I've written (`generate_opml()`) that converts into the proper XML format:

```r
  output$downloadOPML <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('journal-rss-', Sys.Date(), '.opml', sep='')
    },
    content = function(con) {
      opml <- generate_opml(db)
      cat(saveXML(opml), file = con)
    }
  )
```

However, I want to be able to export only selected rows, which seems easiest `DT::datatable()`. This can easily be exported as CSV and few other formats:

```r
output$user_table <- renderDataTable({
      datatable(
        db,
        selection = "none",
        filter="top",
        rownames = FALSE,
        extensions = c("Buttons", "Select"),

        options = list(
          select = TRUE,
          dom = 'Blfrtip',
          buttons =
            list('copy', 'print', list(
              extend = 'collection',
              buttons = list(
                list(extend = 'csv', filename = "File", title = NULL,
                     exportOptions = list(modifier = list(selected = TRUE))),
                list(extend = 'excel', filename = "File", title = NULL,
                     exportOptions = list(modifier = list(selected = TRUE)))),
              text = 'Download'
            ))
        ),
        class = "display"
      )
```

So my question is whether it's possible to export a custom file type with `DT::datatable()`? Or is there a way to get `downloadButton()` to only export selected rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indices of the selected rows are in `input$ID_rows_selected` where `ID` is the output id of the datatable. So you can do:

```r
  output$downloadOPML <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('journal-rss-', Sys.Date(), '.opml', sep='')
    },
    content = function(con) {
      dat <- db[input$user_table_rows_selected, ]
      opml <- generate_opml(dat)
      cat(saveXML(opml), file = con)
    }
  )
```

However I'm not sure this works if you use the `Select` extension. Maybe with `server=FALSE`. Please check.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! If nothing is selected, it returns `NULL` - to avoid that I've just included an `if (!is.null(input$user_table_rows_selected)){` statement and it works like a charm! (And as I didn't need the `Select` extension in the end, I haven't tried with it).